# How to delete file after sync from EC2 to s3

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a file system where files can be dropped into an EC2 instance and I have a shell script running to sync the newly dropped files to an s3 bucket.  I'm looking to delete the files off the E2C instance once they are synced.  Specifically the files are dropped into the "yyyyy" folder.

Below is my shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

    inotifywait -m -r -e create "yyyyy" | while read -r NEWFILE
    do
            if  lsof  | grep "$NEWFILE" ; then
                    echo "$NEWFILE";
            else
                    sleep 15
                    aws s3 sync yyyyy s3://xxxxxx-xxxxxx/
            fi
```

Comment: Can you explain why you do not use `rm` after the sync or `aws s3 mv` ?

Comment: I would capture the result of the "aws s3 sync yyyyy s3://xxxxxx-xxxxxx/" line as a variable and confirm that the return code indicated the sync was successful. Then write an if successful routine to rm the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `aws s3 sync`, you could use `aws s3 mv` (which is a 'move').

This will copy the file to the destination, then delete the original (effectively 'moving' the file).

Can also be used with `--recursive` to move a whole folder, or `--include` and `--exclude` to specify multiple files.